# A-sky a-frame rounded borders

Tags: aframe, virtual-reality, rounded-corners, 360-virtual-reality, sky

I'm setting an a-sky element with an image 360:

```
<a-sky id="sky_salon_izq" src="#salon_izq"></a-sky>
```

The img show cool in normal mode:

[normal mode img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ris90.jpg)

But i have problems when enter in vr mode, the walls appears rounded in extremes:

[vr mode img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TFDFS.jpg)

In vr mode, if i see to the top, the rounded walls are seeing well, but they rounded when i see from top to bottom.

i'm playing with the options in aframe sky, with no results:

[aframe sky component](https://aframe.io/docs/1.0.0/primitives/a-sky.html)

¿any suggestions?

thanks.

Answer (score 0):

That's expected image distortion. It should look straight when viewed through the lenses of a headset (Cardboard, Rift, Quest...)

Comment: Hello Diego:

Thanks for your response, with all the global problems I can't continue with this project.

I had made a demo:

https://monalproyect.glitch.me/

In an iPhone with a cheap glass like cardboard, I'm seeing the distortion in the walls.

This behavior is produced by the cheap glass? Or is for the library.

Maybe i must try in a more expensive glass.

Thanks.